# Warning: Argument is non numeric

Tags: r

I am new to R, so please forgive my ignorance before hand.

I have a dataset that looks like this. jetleg.dat being my dataset.

```
treatment    phaseshift
control       0.53
control       0.36
  light      -0.78
  light      -0.86
```

I need to get the mean for treatment and phaseshift.

When I do the calculation,

```
control <- jetlag.dat[jetlag.dat$treatment == 'control',]$percent
light <- jetlag.dat[jetlag.dat$treatment == 'light',]$percent

mean(control)
mean(light)
```

I get this notification:

> Warning message:
>   In mean.default(control) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I understand that control and light are non numeric, but I thought I accounted for that in calculation.  I have done this before like this and it worked.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give a reproducibe code? Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to a column named `percent`, which I can't see. I'll assume it should be `$phaseshift`.

```
control <- jetlag.dat[jetlag.dat$treatment == 'control',]$phaseshift
light <- jetlag.dat[jetlag.dat$treatment == 'light',]$phaseshift

mean(control)
mean(light)
```

If this still gives you the same error, try to wrap it in `as.numeric`.

`mean(as.numeric(control))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be mostly syntax that is your issue here.

First, you call `$percent` when your variable is names `phaseshift` in the previous line.

Second, the `$percent` or `$phaseshift` needs to be before the brackets

and Finally, there shouldn't be any comma after `jetlag.dat$treatment == "control"` statement.

Here is a revised version of your code and it works:

```
df <- data.frame(treatment = c("control", "control", "light", "light"),
             phaseshift = c(0.53, 0.36, -0.78, -0.86))

control <- df$phaseshift[df$treatment == "control"]
light <- df$phaseshift[df$treatment == "light"]

control_mean <- mean(control)
light_mean <- mean(light)
```

Hope this helps!